# Getting ArgumentNullException on empty Entry

Tags: regex, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to validate a user typed email in Xamarin.Forms with Regex. For that I require that the pattern includes:

```
var emailPattern = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
    @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";
```

Then I match the typed email with the pattern:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(Email, emailPattern) || Email == null)
            {
                    EmailIsWrong = true;
            }
            else{
                EmailIsWrong = false;
            }
```

However, an error occurs, which is `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input` on my if statement. I tried fixing it by having `Email == null`. This error occurs whenever I let the entry be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, change the order of operands may help.
Like:

```
if (Email == null || !Regex.IsMatch(Email, emailPattern))
        {
                EmailIsWrong = true;
        }
        else{
            EmailIsWrong = false;
        }
```

If the first operand is satisfied, the second operand will be skipped

Comment: My preference/recommendation would be to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email)` instead of `Email == null`.